# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline use global timestamps options

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my scripted pipeline I would like to set global `timestamps` and `ansicolor` option.

Below scripted pipeline not working. How can we add these two options in scripted pipeline?

**Declarative Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  options {
    timestamps()
    ansiColor('xterm')  
  }

  stages {    
    stage('Checkout') {
      agent { label 'linux' }
      steps{
      echo "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Scripted Pipeline**

```
node('linux') {
options {
    timestamps()
    ansiColor('xterm')

  }  
    stage('Pre Build Setup') {
        task('Display env') {
        echo "test"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a scripted pipeline, all you have to do is to wrap your script with `timestamps` and `ansiColor('xterm')` steps as shown in the example down below:

```groovy
node {
    timestamps {
        ansiColor("xterm") {

            stage("A") {
                echo 'This is stage A'
                sh 'printf "\\e[31mHello World\\e[0m\\n"'
                sh "sleep 3s"
            }

            stage("B") {
                echo "This is stage B"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to use in global, like this Jenkinsfile https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/Jenkinsfile

Comment: What do you mean by global? One of the key differences between declarative and scripted pipeline is that in the scripted pipeline, everything inside `node` is more or less a freestyle script. There are no blocks like `options`, `environment` etc. In the declarative pipeline, you have a predefined structure, and you need to stick to that structure. That is why in the scripted pipeline the only way to achieve the same effect is to wrap your freestyle script with those steps, in one way or another.

Comment: if you look at the link, they have defined like this `options {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20', artifactNumToKeepStr: '20', daysToKeepStr: '30'))
    timestamps()
    ansiColor('xterm')
    disableResume()
    durabilityHint('PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED')
  }` If I do the same, it not working

Comment: it gives this error message `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'options' found among steps`

Comment: The link you are referring to uses the declarative pipeline, not the scripted one. The declarative pipeline starts with `pipeline {}` while the scripted pipeline starts with the `node {}`. The error you see is caused by the fact that there is no such step as `options` and you can't use it the same way you do it in the declarative pipeline. `options` among the others like `environment` etc. is a part of the declarative pipeline syntax only. Check out Jenkins Pipeline Syntax documentation page - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/ It explains it quite clearly.

Comment: oh yes, its declarative pipeline. sorry for confusion.